# jquery code working like media screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a jQuery code working like `@media (min-width:768px) {}` I tried

```
$(window).one('resize',function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 800){
        size = true;
        mob();
    }
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

this code also but it works but if I click one time and re-size it not work correctly. can any one help me. is there jQuery code working like 100% `@media (min-width:768px) {}`

Comment: Check console, maybe your code throws some error and that's why script stops working...

Comment: `$( window ).resize(function() {});` or pure JS `window.onresize = function(event) {};`

Comment: shouldnt `one` be `on`?

Comment: if you only want to perform the action when the width crosses the 768px boundary, you can use a media query listener: http://tylergaw.com/articles/reacting-to-media-queries-in-javascript

Comment: If its purely a layout and display thing, you might be better using css, simply add styles specific to <=768px width and those for >768px, it will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a media query listener instead:

```
var mediamatch = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
mediamatch.addListener(handleMediaChange);

function handleMediaChange = function (mediaQueryList) {
    if (mediaQueryList.matches) {
         // The browser window is at least 768px wide
    }
    else {
        // The browser window is less than 768px wide
    }
}
```

This will only fire when the width crosses the 768px boundary.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this:

```
$(window).resize(function {
    if ($(window).width() > 768){ // Equals min-width: 768px
        //Your code goes here
    }
});
```